# failed to ptrace(ATTACH) child

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, alpine-linux

I am running a Sonata application atop Symfony 2 in an Alpine Linux container. Most of my application works, but when I try to save a record, I get a message saying

> An error has occurred during update of item "my item". ("My item" is the title I gave the item in my CMS.)

Digging a bit deeper shows a bunch of errors that look like this:

> php-fpm_1        | [08-May-2018 10:07:40] WARNING: [pool www] child
>   254, script '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET
>   /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.429745 sec), logging php-fpm_1
>   | [08-May-2018 10:07:40] ERROR: failed to ptrace(ATTACH) child 253:
>   Operation not permitted (1) php-fpm_1        | [08-May-2018 10:07:40]
>   WARNING: [pool www] child 253, script '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php'
>   (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.208508 sec),
>   logging php-fpm_1        | [08-May-2018 10:07:40] ERROR: failed to
>   ptrace(ATTACH) child 248: Operation not permitted (1) php-fpm_1
>   | [08-May-2018 10:07:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 248, script
>   '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing
>   too slow (2.209222 sec), logging php-fpm_1        | [08-May-2018
>   10:07:40] ERROR: failed to ptrace(ATTACH) child 247: Operation not
>   permitted (1) php-fpm_1        | [08-May-2018 10:07:40] WARNING: [pool
>   www] child 247, script '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET
>   /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.209334 sec), logging

... which confuses me, since everything I've read says that these types of errors correspond to a logging tool that isn't even present in Alpine Linux by default.

I'm a bit lost. What steps should I take to continue debugging this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my CMS problem had nothing to do with the logged message. I simply needed to correct a bit of invalid information that I was submitting in a form to adhere to a constraint.